# How can I read and compare numbers from a text file?

Tags: java

I've a text file and eclipse reads that without problem. The problem is that I don't know how I can hold the numbers from the FileReader. My program is supposed to read a text from a file that file has 2 names with their school points.

For example:

> Jack 30 30 30
>   Martin 20 20 30

How can I find the one with the greater points?

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String name = null;
    try {
        Scanner keybord = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter in file name");
        String filename = keybord.nextLine();
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        while (file.hasNext())
        {
            name = file.nextLine();
            System.out.println(name);

            ///?? what do i have to write to compare to persons points
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("The file does not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the first things you should learn is to read the API of certain classes/libraries to understand how a method works and what it does. In this case: [`Scanner#nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--). This is not the method you want to call here. Use `Scanner#next()` instead (check the JavaDoc/API to find out why). Then use `Scanner#nextInt()` to read the numbers and store them [in a collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/). From there you can access the numbers and compare them.

Comment: Just create a class (such as `StudentPoint`) to hold both student's `name` and `point`. And when you read a line, split it to values and instantiate your object, add it to a `List`. Finally, iterate through your `List` and find out which you want.

Comment: Thank you Tom :) I'll read more about scanner and buffer classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, it is not an efficient method, but I solved the problem with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String name = null;
    int i = 0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    try
    {
        Scanner keybord = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter in file name");
        String filename = keybord.nextLine();
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        while (file.hasNext())
        {
            name = file.next();
            System.out.println(name + " ");

            while (file.hasNextInt())
            {
                i = i + file.nextInt();
            }
            if (i < min)
            {
                min = i;
            }
            System.out.println("min " + min);
            if (i > max)
            {
                max = i;
            }
            System.out.println("max " + max);
            i = 0;
        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File does not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great to see that you found an answer to your question by doing research and I guess a bit of trial and error. Don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) your answer :).

Comment: Thank you Tom SO MUCH :) and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the most efficient way of solving it, but I gave it a shot. It isn't the full code for comparing multiple lines but you can just run this through a while loop until the file doesn't have next like you were already doing. Once you run this through you can store the value of each line to a variable and then compare the variables. ex: boolean xIsBigger x > y;. Then if it is true, x is the bigger number but if it is false then you know y is the bigger number. Hope this helps.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        String line = "Jack 20 20 20";

        line = line.replaceAll("[^0-9]", " ");

        line = line.replaceFirst("^ *", "");

        line = line.replaceAll(" ", "+");

        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        System.out.println(engine.eval(line));

}

}
```

System output: 60.

Comment: Thanks to refer `ScriptEngineManager`. This is first time I know about it :D

Comment: This solution feels a lot like trying to kill a bee with a sledgehammer.

Comment: Thank you so much for help @Tom and Devan. I know my code is so long because i don't know so much methods and classes :(